# Android Firebase Firestore StorageException has occurred

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Not able to store values in Firestore due to the error given below and also instead of taking the value of `name.getText().toString()` its taking null. help me with the same.

Error:

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
> Object does not exist at location.
> Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
> E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
> java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
> at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)

CODE:

```
DocumentReference docReference = firestore.collection("users").document(userID);
Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("fName",name.getText().toString());
user.put("email",mail.getText().toString());
user.put("phone",firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber());

docReference.set(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
    finish();

   }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
         @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Log.d("LOG", "onFailure: Failed to Create User " + e.toString());
     }
     });
```

Comment: That's a Cloud Storage Exception which thrown when you try to read a file that doesn't exist. It has nothing to do with Firestore. At which particular line of code occurs?

Comment: @AlexMamo its storing null type for the first two user.put statement instead of String type in firestore,  also addOnCompleteListener is getting executed after that and then the error is coming. Please help me with same

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate the exact line of code at which it occurs.